# Grouping x values on a line graph with Plotly on JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I'm having trouble grouping the values in my x-axis. I am trying to get the values aggregated by month, instead of being viewed daily.

Here is an example of what I have created right now:

[JS version(What I have right now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqUOG.png)

Here is an example of how I want it displayed:

[How I want the graph displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGlV7.png)

This is the current code I have right now. I am not sure if I am suppose to edit anything in the layout or create a function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
makeChart(2018);


$('#yearFilter').change(function() {
    let year = $(this).val();
    makeChart(year);
})
```

});

function makeChart(year) {

```
d3.select("#line-graph").empty();
d3.select("#line-graph").append();

url = "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/833y-fsy8.json?"

var date = `$where=occur_date%20between%20%27${year}-01-01T00:00:00%27%20and%20%27${year+1}-01-01T00:00:00%27`;

var fullUrl = url + date;


var boroughs = []
var fatalities = []


d3.json(fullUrl).then(function(response) {
    console.log(data);

    var boroughs = response.map(x => x.occur_date);
    boroughs = [...new Set(boroughs)];

    var murderData = {};
    var nonFatalData = {};

    boroughs.forEach(borough => {
        let specBorough = response.filter(x => x.occur_date === borough);
        let totalFatals = specBorough.map(x => x.statistical_murder_flag).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        murderData[borough] = totalFatals;

        console.log(boroughs);
        let nonFatals = specBorough.length - totalFatals;
        nonFatalData[borough] = nonFatals;
    });


    var trace1 = {
        x: Object.keys(nonFatalData),
        y: Object.values(nonFatalData),
        name: 'NonFatal Shootings',

        type: 'line',
        marker: {
            color: 'rgb(165,0,0)'

        }
    };

    var trace2 = {
        x: Object.keys(murderData),
        y: Object.values(murderData),
        name: 'Fatal Shootings',

        type: 'line',
        marker: {
            color: 'rgb(198, 36, 28)'
        }
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    var layout = {
        title: 'Total Shootings By Year',
        //barmode: 'stack'
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('line-graph', data, layout);
});
```

};

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: both are the same images